# Returning generic type which is a specific collection based on type passed to parameter

Tags: java-8

I am trying to write a generic class that by default returns a collection but if calling function requires a specific type say List or Set, the method should be able to yield it. Is that possible in java ? Do correct me if iam not doing it rightly.

```
public <U extends Collection> U saveOrUpdate(Iterable<T> entities, Class<U> klass) {
    Iterable<T> savedEntities = this.repository.save(entities);
    Type type = klass.getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
    ParameterizedType pt = (ParameterizedType) type;
    if (pt.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase(Set.class.getName())) {
        return StreamSupport.stream(savedEntities.spliterator(), false)
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
    } else if (pt.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase(List.class.getName())) {
        return StreamSupport.stream(savedEntities.spliterator(), false)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    } else {
        return StreamSupport.stream(savedEntities.spliterator(), false)
                .collect(Collectors.toCollection());
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just try it? Or even better, make it a standalone example and compile it. `Collectors.toCollection()` expects a `Supplier` argument, BTW.

Comment: I tried but compiler is giving error on specific type collector Collectors.toSet() and Collectors.toList()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do not think there is a type-safe solution with your approach - you *could* cast the returned collection to `U`, I guess...

Instead of passing the `Class`, wouldn't it be easier if you'd pass in the `Supplier` for `Collectors#toCollection`?

```
public <U extends Collection<T>> U saveOrUpdate(Iterable<T> entities, Supplier<U> supplier) {
    Iterable<T> savedEntities = this.repository.save(entities);
    return StreamSupport.stream(savedEntities.spliterator(), false)
                        .collect(Collectors.toCollection(supplier));
}
```

Then you'd have full control over the result type, e.g.:

```
saveOrUpdate(entities, HashSet::new);  // constructor as Supplier
```

And it even type-checks.